# How to update a text label by python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I use a Button to call a function (root.write_username())

```
  GridLayout
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: "Login"

        TextInput:
            id: username
            hint_text: root.usernamehint
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Gooo"
            on_release: root.write_username()
```

The Funktion (def write_username(self):) write username in a text file.
After that, the Funktion should update a Label in the SecondWindow with the entered username.

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    usernamehint = StringProperty(str(read_username()))


#####Weiterleitung SecondScreen, wenn ein Benutzername eingegeben wurde wird dieser gespeichert#####

    def write_username(self):
        if str(self.username.text) is "":
            self.manager.current = "second"
            pass
        else:
            f = open("username.text", "w")
            f.write(str(self.username.text))
            f.close()
          #######befor go to second the label in second should be updated but how?#####
            self.manager.current = "second"
```

```
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    username_label: usernamelabel

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        ####this label should be updated####
        Label:
            id : usernamelabel
            text: root.username
            color: 1,0,1,1
```

I know there are some posts about updating a kivy label with python but I didn´t get an answer in my case. 
Thanks for your help!

In Case you need my entire code

```
##########################Pyton#############################
import random
import operator
import time
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kivy.require("1.11.1")


def read_username():
    f = open("username.text", "r")
    username = str(f.read())
    f.close()
    return username

    pass


def choicehello():
    spruch = ["Gib jedem Tag die Chance, der schönste deines Lebens zu werden. – Mark Twain",
              "Wenn du die Absicht hast, dich zu erneuern, tu es jeden Tag. – Konfuzius",
              ]
    hello = random.choice(spruch)

    return hello

    pass


#####Eingabe Username falls Unbekannt########

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    usernamehint = StringProperty(str(read_username()))


#####Weiterleitung SecondScreen, wenn ein Benutzername eingegeben wurde wird dieser gespeichert#####

    def write_username(self):
        if str(self.username.text) is "":
            self.manager.current = "second"
            pass
        else:
            f = open("username.text", "w")
            f.write(str(self.username.text))
            f.close()

            self.manager.current = "second"




####Begrüßung des Users, Level Auswahl, Einstellungen, Highscores#####

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    username = StringProperty(str(read_username()))
    userhello = StringProperty(str(choicehello()))

class Game1Window(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("mathe.kv")


class MatheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MatheApp().run()


########################KV########################################

WindowManager:
    LoginScreen:
    SecondWindow:
    Game1Window:

<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login"
    username: username


    GridLayout
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: "Login"

        TextInput:
            id: username
            hint_text: root.usernamehint
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Gooo"
            on_release: root.write_username()





<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"


    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: root.userhello
            color: 1,0,1,1

        Label:
            text: "Wähle ein Level"

        Label:
            id : usernamelabel
            text: root.username
            color: 1,0,1,1

        ScrollView:

            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10



                Button:
                    text: "Test"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "game1"

                Button:
                    text: "Test"

                Button:
                    text: "Test"

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login"



<Game1Window>:
    name: "game1"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Until now it works, but I didn´t find a solution to update the text on Label 
after the kv has been read.

Comment: For example, I would like to do a calculation in python and pass new data to a text label in kV and show them on screen.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are looking to update the text of a Label from the Python code. To achieve this, you'll need to use the ObjectProperty

**kv code (snippet)**

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    username:username
    Label:
        id : username
        text: 'hello'
        color: 1,0,1,1
```

**python code (snippet)**

```
class function(self):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    if logic1:
        self.username.text = 'text for logic 1'
    else:
        self.username.text = 'text for logic 2'
```

Hope this was able to answer your query
:)